# Unable to use new Date() in Typescript - TS2554: Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0

Tags: typescript, date, constructor

I am trying to use a js date with Ts and seemingly unable to .

### Usage

```
<Date variant="body2">on {format(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy')}</Date>
```

### Error

```
Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0.  TS2554

  > 162 |             <Date variant="body2">on {format(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy')}</Date>
        |                                              ^
    163 |           </>
    164 |         )}
    165 |       </UploadBox>
```

[image]

Comment: If you are using date-fns to format, you can pass into it Date.now() instead of new Date(). Never seen this, what version of typescript are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have imported a React component named `Date` into scope and shadowed the built-in `Date` object.  Your code *probably* looks like this:

```js
import { Date } from 'some/ui/library';

// ... snip ...
function MyCoolComponent(props) {
  return <Date>{format(...)}</Date>;
}
```

If you want access to the global `Date` object you need to *either*:

- Import the component in another way (e. g. `import { Date as DateElement } from 'some/ui/library';`) **or**
- Access the global `Date` object off of the global (using `window` or `globalThis`) - `<Date>{format(new window.Date())}</Date>;`

Comment: Ahh brilliant. I had oddly not considered this... ```const DateStyled = styled(Text)`
  color: #6d6b8c;
``` indeed indeed ;)